# When importing data into ChemoSpec, I get: Error in `[.data.frame`(temp, , 2) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r

I'm new to R (and any kind of programming language in general) and was hoping for a package to help analyze some HPLC data. My script:

```
library(ChemoSpec)
spec <- files2SpectraObject(gr.crit=c("Control","AC","Fifty"),
        gr.cols=c("auto"), freq.unit="minutes", int.unit="mAU",
        descrip="hplc test data", fileExt=".csv", 
        out.file="hplc test data", debug=TRUE)
```

And the output:

> The default behavior of this function has changed as of July 2016. See
>   ?files2SpectraObject.  Really: please read it!
>
> files2SpectraObject is checking the first file
>
> files2SpectraObject will now import your files Importing file: 
>   AC_3G_L_1_220_trim.csv  Error in `[.data.frame`(temp, , 2) : undefined
>   columns selected

I've got the ChemoSpec pdf and formatted my files accordingly into two columns, no headers, .csv format. Any suggestions as to what I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

I am the author of `ChemoSpec` -- sorry for the delay in answering!

You probably need to add `sep = ","` to your `files2SpectraObject` call.  You may also need to set the header and possibly the decimal marker.  The only way to know is to open one of your csv files in a plain text editor and see what it looks like.  `ChemoSpec` now allows a lot of flexibility in the format of the csv file, because it turns of that not all instrument manufacturers feel that csv means "comma separated values".  Plus, different countries have different standards for the decimal marker (and your instrument may or may not be set up to reflect typical local standards).  This is all detailed in `?files2SpectraObject`.

There is also a new version of `ChemoSpec` on CRAN as of a few days ago.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I opened one of the data files in Notepad and the values are indeed separated by commas and decimals are used as expected for the US. Does it matter where I add `sep = ","` in the call? Can I just tuck it at the end? I didn't see anything in the help text, but I will update and read again this afternoon.

Comment: Anyplace in the call will work since it is a named argument.  Feel free to e-mail separately with any additional questions.

Comment: I named my 456 `.csv` files with "time_0x" after their corresponding recording time in the full sepctrum. `files2SpectraObject` now reads them in the order "time_01","time_010",... instead of "time_01",time_02",...! Further I get an error at the end: "Error in ncol(x@nir) : 
  trying to get slot "nir" from an object (class "Spectra") that is not an S4 object "
What does that error message imply given that it appears too when I try to `loadObject(mydata)` following your Vignette? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Capt.Krusty You should file this as a [Github issue](https://github.com/bryanhanson/ChemoSpec/issues) rather than a comment to a different question.

Comment: Found that there is some error with another package (don't know which one) for that problem. Thanks for advice to look up issues on your [GitHub](https://github.com/bryanhanson/ChemoSpec/issues/17) page.

Comment: @BryanHanson The warning appears (for now; I keep looking which one too) after loading the `spectacles` package (which I need for the `snv`function to compare smoothing process) :)